# Locking rows on top of a subquery

Tags: postgresql, locking, postgresql-10

Consider the following query:

```
select qq.id from (
    select id from log 
    where create_date <= now() - interval '1 month'
    limit 1000
) qq
order by qq.id
for update;
```

Docs say:

> When a locking clause appears at the top level of a SELECT query, the
>   rows that are locked are exactly those that are returned by the query;

So I suppose that this query locks 1000 rows ordered by log.id and satisfying the where condition. Is my assumption correct ? The query plan shows two LockRows. How this can be explained?

The query plan:

```
QUERY PLAN

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 LockRows  (cost=127.96..140.46 rows=1000 width=40) (actual time=7.633..7.877 rows=1000 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=127.96..130.46 rows=1000 width=40) (actual time=7.633..7.734 rows=1000 loops=1)
         Sort Key: qq.id
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 103kB
         ->  Subquery Scan on qq  (cost=0.00..78.13 rows=1000 width=40) (actual time=0.108..7.174 rows=1000 loops=1)
               ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..68.13 rows=1000 width=14) (actual time=0.100..6.749 rows=1000 loops=1)
                     ->  LockRows  (cost=0.00..21475436.14 rows=315198214 width=14) (actual time=0.098..6.601 rows=1000 loops=1)
                           ->  Seq Scan on log (cost=0.00..18323454.00 rows=315198214 width=14) (actual time=0.057..2.329 rows=1000 loops=1)
                                 Filter: (create_date <= (now() - '1 mon'::interval))
 Planning time: 0.228 ms
 Execution time: 8.044 ms
(11 rows)
```